# collect logs from bash each 24 hours

Tags: bash, sed, date, sort

my idea is to collect logs each 24 hours ,mail it
and flush them after that

i wrote some scatch 
for example
1.var/log/auth

{some info}
2.var/log/something.log
 {some info}

```
list="$(find /var/log -name *.log )"
for file in $list;do
echo  '#############################'
onehourago=$(date --date='1 hours ago' +"%b%e %H:%M:%S")
echo $onehourago | cat $file - |sort| sed "1,/$onehourago/d"
done
```

but still could not understand the problem

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: i cant make a proper list as i want it just a big list without delimeter

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?  It even has an option to mail the log to you.